# Drupal website mysql error Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Today I got a problem with a drupal website connected to a SQL database in Google Cloud SQL (error 502 in my browser).

Accessing the SQL logs I got this entry thousands of times:

2018-10-02 11:49:00.434 ECT
2018-10-02T16:49:00.434633Z 8291808 [Note] Aborted connection 8291808 to db: 'drupal' user: 'root' host: '35.224.213.131' (Got an error reading communication packets)

[screen capture log GOOGLE CLOUD SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaZDl.jpg)

I still could connect from my web server to the SQL server via command line but for some reason I kept getting the same error when I openned the site.

I finally restarted the SQL server and it worked again.

Have any of you encountered this problem?

Answer (score -1):

As you can see over at https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues the message "Aborted connection" usually means that your application is not terminating connections properly, or that you had a network issue.